# Why does not Application install

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I have written a method that check new version of my APP and when it exists, the application download and it should install that. But it can not install the downloaded application and it gives me this error:

There was a problem parsing the package.

But when I uninstall my app and install it again with the downloaded apk file. Everything works fine so my app downloads the file correctly.
But why this could not install it programmatically?

This is my Download code:

```
public long downloadFromUrl(String url, String fileName, String format) {
        String fullFileName = fileName + format;
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
                .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)// Visibility of the download Notification
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fullFileName)// Uri of the destination file
                .setTitle(fullFileName)// Title of the Download Notification
                .setDescription("Downloading...");// Description of the Download Notification

        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        long id = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
        if (format.equals(APK_FORMAT)) {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fullFileName);
            if(file.exists()){
                DownloadReceiver downloadReceiver = new DownloadReceiver(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                downloadReceiver.onReceive(context,intent);
                context.registerReceiver(downloadReceiver,new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
            }
        }
        return id;
    }
```

This is a receiver that when download is completed, runs:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    long receivedId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
    if (file != null) {
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+ ".provider",file);
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: try signing both version with a key before doing this .

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uri;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", destination);
} else {
    uri = Uri.fromFile(destination);
}
    
//Log.d("path",uri.getPath());
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

make sure you have added this permission to your manifest file
Also make sure both version of your APKs are signed and with same key.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

I made it work with this code (destination is file object).

Comment: It's not working. And I have another question about my problem, but I don't know can I ask it here or I should create new topic for that.

Comment: just ask another if it isnt about this . btw are your apks signed ? I had the same issue because I was using unsigned apks

Comment: yes, I signed the application but it doesn't work.

Comment: have you granted read/write storage permission?

Comment: Yes, I granted required permissions like read/write storage and request install package. The file has been downloaded successfully.

Comment: on what android version you are testing your application>

Comment: Android version 9 and 10

Comment: it looks like there are some problems with your on receiver.

Comment: What is its problem? I have copied my receiver. Do you see any problem in that?

Comment: are you getting callbacks properly I mean does onreceived get called after your file gets downloaded or just rightaway

Comment: onReceive is called after download file, because this code run the service: registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));